# regular expression attribute in MVC3

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I use regular expression attribute in MVC3 on EMAIL field to give an error message if the email entered contains `no-email.com`?

Comment: no details at all! what programming language? what have you tried? etc

Answer (score 1):

The exact syntax will depend on the language you are using and possibly the method you are using. These examples should help.

You wouldn't normally need a regular expression to match a simple string.

But, if for some reason, it has to be regex, you would just need to escape the hyphen and dot. Like so:

```
no\-email\.com
```

Depending on what you are doing, you may need to match the rest of the email address:

```
(.*?)no\-email\.com
```

You may also want to tie "no-email.com" to the end of the string, like so:

```
(.*?)no\-email\.com$
```

If you also want to match the @ sign to the domain name, do:

```
(.*?)@no\-email\.com$
```